# combination of pspicture and psmatrix

Tags: pstricks

In a prior version I have used the psmatrix environment and it works fine, but I failed to have more frames inside (like this figure). Connecting nodes in psmatrix is much easier as in this example. So I would like to get a hint how to.

- use psmatrix for easy connecting codes and also
- use psframes like this figure and able to connect frames inside a frame.... and also connect inner frames to some frames outside....

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[a3paper,margin=0cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{pstricks}
  \usepackage{pst-node}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{pst-blur}
  \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
  \usepackage{embedall}
  \definecolor{blue}{rgb}{1,0.75,0.8}
  \begin{document}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  \ \\
  \small‎
  psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true,fillstyle=solid,xunit=0.69,yunit=0.69,runit=0.69,nodesep=3pt}‎
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(50,-50)
  \pnode(1,-1){AgileA}
  \pnode(1,-6){AgileB}
  \pnode(1,-7){AgileC}
  \pnode(1,-10){AgileD}
  \pnode(1,-13){AgileE}
  \pnode(1,-16){AgileF}
  \pnode(1,-19){AgileG}
  \pnode(1,-22){AgileH}   
  \pnode(4,-1){nodeAAA}
  \pnode(5.5,-1.75){nodeABA}
  \pnode(9.5,-1.75){nodeABB}
  \pnode(8.25,-3.75){nodeABC}
  \pnode(36,-1){nodeBAA}
  \pnode(36,-2){nodeBAB}
  \pnode(36,-3){nodeBAC}
  \pnode(36,-4){nodeBAD}
  \pnode(36,-5){nodeBAE}
  \rput(AgileA){\pscirclebox[shadow=true,fillcolor=black!100]{.}}
  \rput(AgileB){\pscirclebox[shadow=true,fillcolor=black!100]{.}}
  \rput(nodeAAA){\psframe[shadow=true,filestyle=none,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(8,-5)}

  \rput(nodeABA){\psframebox[shadow=true,fillcolor=white!20]{backlog}}%
  \rput(nodeABB){\psframebox[shadow=true,fillcolor=white!20]{add to backlog}}%(2.5,-1)
  \rput(nodeABC){\psframebox[shadow=true,fillcolor=white!20]{adapt and modifiy}}%(0,0)(2.5,-1)
  \rput(nodeBAA){\psframe[shadow=false,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(2.5,-1)}
  \rput(nodeBAB){\psframe[shadow=false,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(2.5,-1)}
  \rput(nodeBAC){\psframe[shadow=false,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(2.5,-1)}
  \rput(nodeBAD){\psframe[shadow=false,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(2.5,-1)}
  \rput(nodeBAE){\psframe[shadow=false,fillcolor=white!20](0,0)(2.5,-1)}
  \psset{arrows=->,fillstyle=none,arrowinset=0,nodesep=8pt}
  \ncline{AgileA}{AgileB}
  \ncput*[angle=270]{\scriptsize \begin{tabular}{c} Backlog and   \\ Refinement \end{tabular}}
  \ncangle[angleA=-90,angleB=180,nodesepA=9pt,nodesepB=1.5cm]{nodeABA}{nodeABC}
  \end{pspicture}

  \end{document}
  ```

Does anybody have an idea?

Compiling with: pdflatex -enable-write18 thisexample.tex

Any ideas to archive this figure only using psmatrix or a kind of parallel use of both environments?

[image: Examplefigure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\rnode`. And, by the way, test your own examples!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\small‎
\psset{shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true,unit=0.69,nodesep=3pt}‎
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5,0)(50,-10)
\rput(4,-1){\psframe[shadow](0,0)(8,-5)}
\rput(36,-1){\rnode{nodeBAA}{\psframe[shadow=false](0,0)(2.5,-1)}}
\rput(36,-2){\rnode{nodeBAB}{\psframe[shadow=false](0,0)(2.5,-1)}}
\rput(36,-3){\rnode{nodeBAC}{\psframe[shadow=false](0,0)(2.5,-1)}}
\rput(36,-4){\rnode{nodeBAD}{\psframe[shadow=false](0,0)(2.5,-1)}}
\rput(36,-5){\rnode{nodeBAE}{\psframe[shadow=false](0,0)(2.5,-1)}}
\rput(1,-1){\rnode{AgileA}{\pscircle[shadow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black]{2mm}}}
\rput(1,-6){\rnode{AgileB}{\pscircle[shadow,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black]{2mm}}}
\ncline{AgileA}{AgileB}
\ncput*{\scriptsize\shortstack{Backlog and\\ Refinement}} 
\rput(5.5,-1.75){\rnode{nodeABA}{\psframebox[shadow]{backlog}}}
\rput(9.5,-1.75){\rnode{nodeABB}{\psframebox[shadow]{add to backlog}}}
\rput(8.25,-3.75){\rnode{nodeABC}{\psframebox[shadow]{adapt and modify}}}
\ncangle[angleA=-90,angleB=180,arrows=->]{nodeABA}{nodeABC}
\ncangle[angleA=-90,angleB=180,arrows=->,offsetB=-0.5]{nodeABB}{nodeBAB}
\ncangle[angleA=-90,angleB=180,arrows=->,offsetB=-0.5]{nodeABC}{nodeBAE}
\rput(4,-1){\psframe(0,0)(8,-5)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste error during pasting the code. Tested but a typo. Sorry.